# Getting Access is Denied of an external drive

Tags: hard-drive, drivers

Few weeks back my Laptop died. I tried to save the data. I bought an enclosure and attached the drive to another laptop. However Every time I try to access it , I get Access denied.

Hard drive is HTs5410109E680.

I have not been able to find the  driver.  Windows install this as a generic hard drive

Correction: I Use UNitek USB3 to SATA Adapter to attach the hard drive, Can this be cause of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this is a security permissions settings issue, right-click the drive and click `sharing and security` from the dropdown, in the `Security` tab go to `Advanced`, then `Ownership` on the next window, and replace the owner with "everyone".

If there is no `security` tab open Control Panel, open `Folder options`. In the `View` tab scroll all the way to the bottom and uncheck `Use simple file sharing`. Slightly different for different versions of Windows but all in the same place as far as I remember.